# random: not enough state (1 bytes); ignored

Tags: python, linux, macos

Not sure what the above error means.  I just installed ghmm on my mac and get this error every time I do a `import ghmm`.  I do not get this message on my ghmm install on my linux machine and other than that all functions appear to be fine.

I wondering if anyone has seen this before and if there's anything I can do to get rid of this.  The only thing I did different between the two installs was the autogen.sh file was refering to "libtoolize" which doesn't exist on my mac so I changed it to its replacement "glibtoolize" which allowed it to compile and install fine.

Any suggestions on what this error actually means(and hopefully how I can solve it) would be great.

(I couldn't find the answer on google but this program does not appear to be specific to ghmm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to be corrected on this, but at a guess I'd say this has nothing to do directly with `ghmm` or your compile tools. I think the error message you're seeing is coming from the BSD random number functions that OSX uses (they are [documented here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/random.3.html)).

Assuming that `ghmm` is causing the warning (and not python), it *might* be possible to configure the build process to use plain old `rand` or some other PRNG. Alternatively, maybe you can find the right place to add a call to `initstate()` (see above doc link) to provide the state information it wants.

This bit from the man page probably points to your problem:

> If initstate() is called with less than 8 bytes of state information, or if setstate() detects that the state information has been garbled, error messages are printed on the standard error output.

Comment: I agree..I looked around and don't think its ghmm specific. I'll try to see if I can follow your advice and report back.

Answer (score 2):

eaj is correct that initstate needs more than 8 bytes for state information. The best way to do this for ghmm is with either the --enable-gsl or --with-rng=bsd option for ./configure. --with-rng=bsd makes the type "ghmm_rng_state_t" 8 bytes instead of 1. See rng.h in the ghmm directory.

Answer (score 0):

The ghmm web site says this about "libtoolize":

Mac OS X: 10.6 ships with a broken libtool which breaks the installation (and it also ships with Python 2.5, so you need an update for that). James Howard posted a solution on the mailing list: [Ghmm-list] Compiling in OS X 10.6
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=25874107
HTH

Comment: yup. I saw that, followed the steps and it still didn't work. The port command installs the glibtoolize, which is why I had to change the reference in the build code.